# How to know if the vibration system requires one degree of freedom or two? and how to pick the right coordinate to describe the movement?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, harmonic-oscillator, vibrations, degrees-of-freedom

I want to know a trick that helps me understand oscillatory systems and how to pick the correct general coordinates that describe the movement, I tried everything but I still can't get the solution right, Like in this image which coordinate is a general coordinate is it ${\theta}\; or\;{\varphi}$? or both? "the disc is rolling without sliding"
[image: Mechanical system that represents a disc of mass "M" and radius R linked with a vertical bar of mass "m" using the horizontal rod "AC" that has no mass]

Comment: Can the yellow circle slide on the plane surface (i.e. rotate and translate
independently)? Or can it only roll without sliding?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It only rolls without sliding, Thank you for bringing that up I forgot to add it @ThomasFritsch

Answer (score 1):

[image]

There is no trick.

If you take the linkage AC out the disk can rotate $~\theta~$ and move towards  $~x~$ ,independent of the rotation $~\varphi~$ . The kinematic equation form the „linkage“ is

$$x=\frac l2\sin(\varphi)\approx \frac l2\varphi $$

The rolling condition is

$$x=R\,\theta$$

You obtained two constraint equations for the three degrees of freedom $~x,\theta,\varphi~$ , thus you have one generalized coordinate, you can choose x or $~\theta~$ or $~\varphi$ for this problem . In general the generalized coordinates must „covered „ the space of motion without mathematical singularity

---

with the kinetic energy
$$T=\frac{I_d}{2}\,\dot\theta^2+\frac{I_r}{2}\,\dot\varphi^2+\frac{M}{2}\dot x^2$$

and the potential energy

$$U=-\frac{k}{2}\left(\frac{l\,\varphi}{2}\right)^2-F_d\,\varphi$$

where $~I_d~$ the inertia of the disk, , $~I_r~$ is the inertia of the rod and $~F_d~$ is the damper force.

with $~\varphi~$ the generalized coordinate you obtain the equation of motion

$$\ddot\varphi+\frac{R^2\,k\,l^2}{I_d\,l^2+I_r\,4\,R^2}\,\varphi+
\frac{4\,R^2\,k\,l^2}{I_d\,l^2+I_r\,4\,R^2}\,\dot \varphi=0$$